# How to give relative path in asp.net 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a new folder say XML by using solution explorer. I have added `xml` and `xsl` files say `a.xsl` and `b.xml` in it. How can I fetch  these files by giving relative path?

Example: `transform.Load("~/XML/a.xsl"); //load up the stylesheet`

But I am getting error here that file not found. When I debug it tries to take file from following path

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\~\XML\PersonnelHTML.xsl'.
```

Please suggest the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this is resolved using

[Server.MapPath(path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

so in your example (assuming the XML folder is at the root level of your site) will be

```
transform.Load(Server.MapPath("/XML/a.xsl"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with the help of [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) :

```
 transform.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XML/a.xsl"));
```